# Proving $\alpha(x) = f(x,y_0)$ is a continuous function.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Problem: $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$, if f is continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$ show that the function $\alpha(x) = f(x,y_0)$ is continuous at $x_0$.

I know that a function is continuous if $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0, y_0)}  f(x,y) = f(x_0,y_0)$$

I did this:

$$\lim_{x \to x_0} \ \alpha(x) = \lim_{x \to x_0} \ f(x,y_0) = f(x_0,y_0) = \alpha(x_0)$$

I doubt this is okay, need help, thanks

Comment: **Tip:** Write out the definition for $f$ to be continuous at $(x_0, y_0)$.

Comment: If you have an $\epsilon$,$\delta$ definition of limit for functions of two variables, it can be applied to the analogous definition for functions of one variable.

Comment: It is given that f is continuous at (x0,y0) so:
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (x0,y0)} \ f(x,y) = f(x_0,y_0)$$
I don't know how to go on

Comment: Your attempt here is wrong, because you are basically using what is to be proven, since, in metric spaces such as $\mathbb{R}^n,\,n \in \mathbb{N}$, continuity means that taking limits and 'applying' the function are two commutative/interchangeable 'operations'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha(x) =  f(x,y_0)$ from continuity of $f$ we have $\forall\varepsilon>0\,\exists\delta>0$ such that if $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2<\delta^2$ then $|f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)|<\varepsilon$. 
If $|x-x_0|<\delta$ then $(x-x_0)^2+(y_0-y_0)^2<\delta^2$ an thus $|f(x,y_0)-f(x_0,y_0)|<\varepsilon$ or $|\alpha(x)-\alpha(x_0)|<\varepsilon$. This means 
$$\lim_{x \to x_0} \alpha(x) =  \alpha(x_0)$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$|\alpha(x) - \alpha(x_{0})| = |f(x,y_{0}) - f(x_{0},y_{0})|$ for all suitable $x$. The function $f$ is continuous by assumption; so $|f(x,y) - f(x_{0},y_{0})|$ can be controlled on some open ball of center $(x_{0},y_{0})$. So $|f(x,y_{0}) - f(x_{0},y_{0})|$ can also be controlled on some open ball of center $x_{0}$; so $\alpha$ is continuous at $x_{0}$.

Answer (score 2):

1. What do you know about the composition of continuous functions?
2. Given some $p \in \mathbb{R}$, what do you know about the function
   $$
   \iota_p: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2,\;x \mapsto (x,p)
   $$
   ?

These questions may seem a little mysterious/out of place to you right now, but they are actually hinting at how you are already trying to prove the statement in your question. Only, you are making implicit assumptions...

**Alternatively**, but very similar, let $(x_n)_n$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ with $\lim_n\, x_n = x_0$. To prove continuity of $\alpha$ at $x_0$, you have to show $\lim_n\, \alpha(x_n) = \alpha(x_0)$. Now, consider the sequence $(x_n',\,y_n')_n := (x_n,\,y_0)$ and use what you know about $f$.

Either way, you can circumvent using $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ arguments, using what you (probably) already (should) know/be allowed to use.